# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am getting below error when used SoapClient in the code. How to resolve this?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
 Couldn't load from 'MY URL'
```

Here is my code

```
$wsdl   = 'MY URL';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
));
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1, 'stream_context' => $context));  // The trace param will show you errors
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```